# Linq get all data from specific date, and if data + 1 day is another data and so on

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I got a table called tasks. I got a date that I will get all task from that date and higher.
But I do also want those tasks that are "bounded" to the next day, and the next day and so on.
Eg if I want tasks from today, I'll get that with a simple linq query:

```
var tasks = db.Tasks.Where(x => x.Date >= DateTime.Today);
```

But if there are a task from previous day I want that as well, and previous from that day and so on.
But I do not want the following task if there been one day between two tasks that isn't a task day.

Eg tasks dates: 09/20, 09/19, 09/18, 09/17, 09/16, 09/14, 09/13. In this example I want all task to 09/16.

How is that accomplished in linq?

Comment: Maybe I'm just stupid but I don't understand what you're asking. If you provide us with your Task class, and some sample data and a sample query (plain text is fine) together with the data set you want - I'm sure we can help you.

Comment: Do you mean, starting from the current date and going backwards, you want all task objects up to the first date "gap" (i.e. a gap being present when the difference between two "adjacent" tasks' dates is >1 day)?

Comment: Since these tasks are read from a DB, I suppose you'd like to avoid loading them all in memory before filtering, right?

Comment: @vc74 But how could that be done? We need to know the dates of all tasks.

Comment: @SvenGrosen In that case it might be a big performance issue. Imagine the tasks table is very large, getting all the entities into memory to filter most of them afterwards seems crazy. David Larsson, which DBMS are you on? Can you not write a stored procedure that filters the entities in the db?

Comment: @vc 74. MS SQL and SQL Metal is what I use.

Comment: @vc74 I agree it could be a performance issue, I just don't see how to avoid it given OP's scenario. I'm with you on I'd rather do this in the db.

Comment: @DavidLarsson In this case you should be able to build a stored proc in MS SQL and invoke it from your context as described here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures

Comment: @SvenGrosen: The query could be performed on the DB side (e.g. in a stored procedure, which would be mapped to the C# side by whatever ORM the OP is using.) Gaps can be detected using window functions. Itzik Ben-Gak's book "High-Performance T-SQL using Window Functions" has examples about this.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's define two custom LINQ operators `Pair` and `Unpair`:

- `Pair` turns a sequence of `T` into a sequence of pairs of `T` (`Tuple<T,T>`). Each pair contains two adjacent `T` from the original sequence.

  ```
  static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> Pair<T>(this IEnumerable<T> xs)
  {
      if (xs.Any())
      {
          T last = xs.First();
          foreach (T current in xs.Skip(1))
          {
              yield return Tuple.Create(last, current);
              last = current;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- `Unpair` "flattens" such a pair sequence back into the original sequence:

  ```
  static IEnumerable<T> Unpair<T>(this IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> xs)
  {
      if (xs.Any())
      {
          yield return xs.First().Item1;
          foreach (var x in xs)
          {
              yield return x.Item2;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

With these two operators, you can now express your query as:

```
db.Tasks.Where(task => task.Date <= DateTime.Today)
        .OrderByDescending(task => task.Date)
     // .ToArray() // you might need this if `db.Tasks` queries a database 
        .Pair()
        .TakeWhile(pair => pair.Item1.Date - pair.Item2.Date <= TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
        .Unpair()
```

For a solution with just the in-built LINQ operators, please see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25933686/240733).

Answer (score 1):

Like I promised at the end of [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25933094/240733), here's a solution that uses only in-built LINQ operators.

Given these two definitions:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var oneDay = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

// in-memory cache of all tasks in reverse chronological order (starting from today): 
Task[] tasks = db.Tasks.Where(task => task.Date <= today)
                       .OrderByDescending(task => task.Date)
                       .ToArray(); // see note below for reasons why this is necessary
```

You can write your query as follows:

```
tasks.TakeWhile((task, i) => (i < 1 ? today : tasks[i-1].Date) - task.Date <= oneDay)
```

---

> <sub>**Side note: Why is the `.ToArray()` required?** First, because the lambda function passed to `TakeWhile` requires that the `Task` sequence be random-accessible. Second, because your ORM / DB provider (`db`) might not know how to deal with [this overload of `TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548775.aspx): `.ToArray` forces the execution of the query up to that point, the results are cached in-memory. From there onwards, its all LINQ to Objects, which can deal with that variant of `TakeWhile`. However, [this caching might lead to performance problems](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446279/vc-74) if there are lots of `Task` objects before the current day.</sub>

Comment: Yes that is my problem that it is alot of objects in the DB. And to make it a bit worst. It could be alot of persons as well, each person have it own tasks.

Comment: In that case, I don't think any ORM is powerful enough to support the kind of random-access queries required to solve this problem. The necessary random access means you have to fetch objects into memory. If you want to avoid this, you will probably have to [move the whole query to the database and invoke it from your code e.g. via a stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932743/linq-get-all-data-from-specific-date-and-if-data-1-day-is-another-data-and-so/25933094#comment40598749_25932743 "see comment above").

Comment: Yes it's probably as you say. Was worth a try :)

Comment: @DavidLarsson: You could also change your database schema. For example, add some kind of `TaskSequenceId` column to your `Task` table. All tasks belonging in the same sequence get the same sequence ID. This would reduce the problem to two easier ones: **1.** Whenever you `INSERT` a new task into the database, check if it starts a new sequence, i.e. if its date differs by more than one day from the last task added. If so, use a new sequence ID; otherwise, use the same sequence ID as the last task added. **2.** When querying the DB, simply get all tasks with a particular task sequence ID.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do something like that in linq.
You need loop for that

edited :

List Tasks  tempTask = new List Tasks ();

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 365; i++)
        {
            var tasks = db.Tasks.Where(x => x.Date.ToString("d") == DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i).ToString("d")).ToList();
            if (tasks.Count != 0)
            {
                tempTask.AddRange(tasks);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: you query would still only return tasks with date == DateTime.Now? I don't think you should AddDays on the x.Date

Comment: Thanks for answer. But in this case we assume 365 is enough and we're doing alot of DB querys. But perhaps you are right that it isn't possible to accomplish that in linq in one query

Comment: alex you were right, i changed code and tested it, count must be 0 and removed adddays from Date.
David i think this is the only solution, if there is not a lot of data in Tasks table, you can get list before for query for to pervent database query on each loop

Answer (score 0):

Here's some untested code for you, using recursion:

```
var allTasks = new List<Task>();
RecureseGetTasks(allTasks, DateTime.Now, db);

//presuming your db is DbContext and .Tasks is List<Task>
//just change class names
void RecurseGetTasks(List<Task> allTasks, DateTime dt, DbContext db){
    var tasks = db.Tasks.Where(t=>t.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    if (tasks.Count > 0) {
        allTasks.AddRange(tasks.ToList());
        RecurseGetTasks(allTasks, dt.AddDays(-1), db);
    }
}
```